# Can't disable SSLv3 in Apache + mod_nss

Tags: rhel, ssl, apache-httpd

I am trying to implement TLS through mod_nss in Apache (RHEL 7). As per the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-Web_Servers.html), I have installed **mod_nss** and removed **mod_ssl**.

I have followed the steps outlined in the documentation (see above link), especially making sure that the **NSSProtocol** directive reads as follows (according to the docs, this disables all SSL and TLS protocol versions except TLS version 1 and higher):

```
NSSProtocol TLSv1.0,TLSv1.1
```

Then I restarted Apache and tested whether SSLv3 is enabled:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -ssl3
```

which returns:

```
[root@box1 ~]# openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -ssl3
CONNECTED(00000003)
139894684407712:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:339:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 7 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1442107224
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
[root@box1 ~]#
```

As you can see, the handshake completes (as indicated by **SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 7 bytes**) so that makes me doubt that SSLv3 has been actually disabled.

I have spent countless hours searching for a solution but everything I've been able to found tells me how to disable SSLv3 through mod_ssl, not mod_nss.

Any ideas or clarifications will be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing bad has happened, as you got an handshake error:

> error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

How can client/server decide that the version number is wrong without sending bytes?

Remove the `-ssl3` from your command and you will see the difference:

> SSL handshake has read 4493 bytes and written 499 bytes

Also if the connection is established, `s_client` waits for your input to transfer it to the server. With no connection, it returns.